# Combining arrays - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
print_r($arr);

array(2) {
  ["'type'"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "tell" // <----
    [1]=>
    string(6) "mobile" // <----
    [2]=>
    string(6) "address" // <----
  }
  ["'value'"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "+00.0000000" // tell
    [1]=>
    string(11) "12345678" // mobile
    [2]=>
    string(11) "Blah SQ." // address
  }
}
```

I want a final string like:

```
tell = +00.0000000<br />mobile = 12345678<br />address = Blah SQ.
```

Now it's been more than an hour I'm struggling with this but no results yet, anyone could help me with this? I would appreciate anykind of help.

Thanks

=======================================

What I have tried:

`$arr` is an array so I did:

```
foreach($arr as $values){
// here also $values is an array, so I needed another foreach to access to items:
    $i = 0;
    foreach($values as $items){
        // now making the final output
        @$output.= $items['type'][$i] . '=' . $items['value'][$i] . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your best attempt and explain what the idea behind it is and how exactly it is not working.

Comment: Take a look at `array_combine`.

Comment: @Jon I added what I've done so far.

Comment: OK, nice. So why are you iterating over `$arr` itself? You know there's `$arr['type']` and `$arr['value']`, and what you want is inside. That's what you should be targeting, not `$arr`.

Comment: // here also $values is an array, so I needed another foreach to access to items:

Apparently $arr is also an array

Comment: Remove the '@' symbol from your code, don't suppress any errors.

Comment: @joseconsador I added it because it's empty as the first run of foreach

Comment: @Jon print_r($arr['type']) is undefined :-(

Comment: @behz4d: Ah yes, I didn't notice. `$arr` should have keys `type` and `value`, but it actually has keys `'type'` and `'value'` (the quotes are part of the key itself). This is obviously wrong and has to be fixed at the place it occurs.

Comment: @Jon I'm receiving this as a result of jquery `form.serialize()`, here is the form I'm working with `http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-fields-contact-form`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Basically it does what you request:

```
$yourArray = [
             "type"  => ["tell", "mobile", "address"], 
             "value" => ["+00.0000000", "12345678", "Blah SQ."]
             ];


$combined = array_combine($yourArray["type"], $yourArray["value"]);
```

will be

```
$combined = [
             "tell"    =>"+00.0000000",
             "mobile"  =>"12345678",
             "address" =>"Blah SQ."
            ];
```

Lastly, you can iterate through that array and then join the values:

```
$finalArray=array();

foreach($combined as $type=>$value)
      $finalArray[]="$type=$value";

$string = join("<br/>", $finalArray); // Will output tell=+00.000000<br/>mobile=12345678<br/>address=Blah SQ.
```

It's not the fastest method but you'll learn quite a bit about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (using array_combine by @Dencker)

```
foreach($arr as $values) {
// here also $values is an array, so I needed another foreach to access to items:
    $v = array_combine($values["'type'"], $values["'value'"]);

    foreach($v as $key => $val) {
        // now making the final output
        $output.= $key . '=' . $val . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Try this

```
    $arr = array(
    array(
        "'type'" => array('tell', 'mobile', 'address'),
        "'value'" => array('+00000', '123123', 'foo')
    ),
    array(
        "'type'" => array('tell', 'mobile', 'address'),
        "'value'" => array('+10000', '123123', 'bar')
    ),
    array(
        "'type'" => array('tell', 'mobile', 'address'),
        "'value'" => array('+20000', '123123', 'foobar')
    ),
);

var_dump($arr);

$output = '';

foreach($arr as $values) {
// here also $values is an array, so I needed another foreach to access to items:
    $i = 0;

    foreach($values as $items) {
        // now making the final output
        $output.= $values["'type'"][$i] . '=' . $values["'value'"][$i] . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
}

echo $output;
```

You were referencing the other array in the second loop.

=============================================================
EDIT:

```
var_dump($arr);

array(3) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
       ["type"]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> string(4) "tell" 
            [1]=> string(6) "mobile" 
            [2]=> string(7) "address" 
       } 
       ["value"]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> string(6) "+00000" 
            [1]=> string(6) "123123" 
            [2]=> string(3) "foo" 
       } 
  } 
  [1]=> array(2) { 
       ["type"]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> string(4) "tell" 
            [1]=> string(6) "mobile" 
            [2]=> string(7) "address" 
       } 
       ["value"]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> string(6) "+10000" 
            [1]=> string(6) "123123" 
            [2]=> string(3) "bar" 
       } 
  } 
  [2]=> array(2) { 
      ["type"]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> string(4) "tell" 
            [1]=> string(6) "mobile" 
            [2]=> string(7) "address" 
      } 
      ["value"]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> string(6) "+20000" 
            [1]=> string(6) "123123" 
            [2]=> string(6) "foobar" 
      } 
  } 
} 

OUTPUT:
tell=+00000
mobile=123123
tell=+10000
mobile=123123
tell=+20000
mobile=123123
```

Comment: Thanks but you've changed the question!!! the array I'm working with is in my question... .